# Tabulator copyToClipboard method isn't working as anticipated

Tags: copy-paste, tabulator

I am new to the Tabulator plug-in and I am attempting to copy data from one table to another using the Tabulator `copyToClipboard` method but with no success.

In my application I have created eleven `<div>` elements (one for the [Crew Leader] and one each for up to ten [Crew Members]) to serve as containers for the Tabulator tables to be instantiated.  I am hoping to copy data from the [Crew Leader] table and paste it into each of the affected [Crew Member] tables thus mitigating data re-entry.  This sequence of copy/paste events is triggered by the click event bound to a `<button>` in the header of the [Crew Leader] table.  The following function is called by the `<button>` click event:

```
        function CloneTable() {

            // Verify the [Crew Leader] Tabulator table is present....
            var tableLeader = Tabulator.prototype.findTable("#CrewLeaderTable");
            if (tableLeader.length > 0) {
                alert("The Tabulator table #CrewLeaderTable was found.\ntable.length = " + tableLeader.length);
                tableLeader.copyToClipboard("all");
                alert("The table contents were copied to the clipboard.");
            }
            else {
                alert("The Tabulator table #CrewLeaderTable was not found.");
            }
        }
```

The first `alert` message verifies that the #CrewLeaderTable object has been found as anticipated.  However, the second `alert` verification is never received thus indicating failure of the Tabulator `copyToClipboard` method.

I have read through as much of the relevant Tabulator documentation as I can find and I am hoping I have simply overlooked something in my setup.

The following is a copy of my Tabulator constructor:

```
            var table = new Tabulator(divid, {
                height: "100%",
                layout: "fitDataFill",
                movableRows: true, //enable user movable rows
                tabEndNewRow: true, //create empty new row on tab
                rowContextMenu: myActionContextMenu,
                keybindings: {
                    "navUp": true, //enable navUp keybinding using the "up arrow" key
                    "navDown": true, //enable navDown keybinding using the "down arrow" key
                },
                columns: [
                    { title: "Phase Code", field: "phaseCode", width: 144, editor: "select", editorParams: { values: function (cell) { return window.laborPhaseCodes; } } },
                    { title: "Date Worked", field: "dateComp", hozAlign: "center", sorter: "date", editor: dateEditor },
                    { title: "Start Time", field: "timeStart", hozAlign: "center", sorter: "time", editor: timeEditor },
                    { title: "Finish Time", field: "timeFinish", hozAlign: "center", sorter: "time", editor: timeEditor },
                    { title: "Memo", field: "memo", width: 144, hozAlign: "left", editor: "input" },
                    { title: "<button type='button' id='btnClone' class='btn btn-success btn-sm py-0' style='font-size:10px;'>Clone</button>", headerSort: false, headerClick: tabCloneTable }
                ],
                cellEdited: function (cell) {
                }
            });
```

I have spent a couple of days trying to figure out the best way to "clone" the data from one table into another.  The Tabulator documentation is fairly comprehensive but I fear I have overlooked something.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like copyToClipboard doesn't return the data, it is maintained internally and not accessible.  But, with what you are doing set/getData works fine.
Here is an example, https://jsfiddle.net/nrayburn/19sjg74k/7/.

Basically, what you want to do is call getData on the parent table and setData on the child table.

```
  const crewLeaderTable = Tabulator.prototype.findTable('#CrewLeaderTable')[0];
  const crewMemberTable = Tabulator.prototype.findTable('#CrewMember1Table')[0];
  const crewLeaderData = crewLeaderTable.getData();
  // You could also use replaceData or addData, depending on the requirements
  crewMemberTable.setData(crewLeaderData);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I've added the option to enable the clipboard but I still do not receive confirmation from the second alert (immediately following the .copyToClipboard method) inside my CloneTable() event handler.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work either by calling table.copyToClipboard.  I am going to look into it some more and see if we are doing something wrong or if there is just a bug somewhere.

Comment: As far as I can tell, table.copyToClipboard does not return any value.  It triggers the clipboard to copy the data, but I don't see a way to then paste it programmatically.  The data is stored inside of an event. So, let's revisit your issue.  You just want to copy data from one table and paste it into another using buttons.  So why not use table.getData() and table.setData()?

Comment: Thanks nrayburn-tech.  I will try the alternate method and see what we get.  As an aside, I attempted to use the copyToClipboard method and then immediately paste the table data into Excel (as suggested in the Tabulator docs) but the clipboard was empty and nothing was copied.

Comment: Still no luck. Here's my revised event handler: `var tableLeader = Tabulator.prototype.findTable("#CrewLeaderTable");
if (tableLeader.length > 0) {
    alert("The Tabulator table #CrewLeaderTable was found.\ntable.length = " + tableLeader.length);
    var data = tableLeader.getData();
    alert("The getData() function completed.");
    var rowCount = tableLeader.getDataCount();
    alert("tableLeader row count = " + rowCount);
}`  Neither the getData() nor the getDataCount() methods produce a result.

Comment: findTable() returns an array of tables, so you need to access only 1 before you can call getData(). (tableLeader = Tabulator.prototype.findTable('#CrewLeaderTable')[0]) I will update my answer with an example using get/set Data from one table to another.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am finding very little in the way of meaningful examples with Tabulator.  The documentation is helpful (particularly for open source software) but does not provide extensive use of examples. I have been attempting to work with the findTable() function as an array but still have not managed to get to a point where I can move or replicate data.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The project is primarily maintained by one person. He spends any of his free time trying to meet the request for functionality and bugs, so that leaves him little time to create robust examples. I use the product extensively now, so the least I can do is answer some community questions. Just post them here and I try to look at the recent tabulator questions every few days.

Comment: Yes, I noticed Oli is the author and primary architect of the software.  I am very excited about Tabulator's potential and I will gladly contribute monetarily if I can get it to work. As an aside, I logged a copy of the ```table``` object to the Firefox Web Console and I am definitely seeing the Tabulator object.  My problem seems to lie with unlocking from the array in order to manipulate it.  Thanks again for your assistance.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Many thanks to nrayburn-tech for this very simple but very effective example.  It works perfectly and if my reputation was high enough I would give it an up-vote.  If possible, I would give it 50 up-votes!